# Why/when to use async:false in SPservices

Tags: javascript, spservices

In recent questions related to SPServices

- [SPServices and GetListItemChanges](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157596/spservices-and-getlistitemchanges)
- [rendering, spservices and view title header counts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156197/rendering-spservices-and-view-title-header-counts)
- [Display an Announcement List inside <div> tag](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157618/display-an-announcement-list-inside-div-tag)

I see people use the

```
async:false
```

option.

Is there an issue with the default async:true behaviour I need to become aware of?
or is this an example of people copy/pasting code without understanding what is going on?

#### [SPServices documentation](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices&referringTitle=Documentation)

> async
>
> By default, all of the Web Service operations are called asynchronously
>   with AJAX. Generally, this will be the desired approach, but to force
>   synchronicity, add the async: false option.

In layman's terms:

If you set `async:false` your script will block processing of the rest of the page until the whole (SPservices) script has finished.  Effectivly making the download/processing of the whole page a lot longer.

If you set `async:true` (or leave out this line, because it is the default setting) your script will **NOT** block processing of the rest of the page until the whole (SPservices) script has finished.

So use false only when you really really need it.

Comment: This is more of a discussion than a specific question. Please feel free to edit this to ask something specific and request it to be re-opened, or another option might be to ask it on the SPServices site.