# How to get value of person or group field using jquery

Tags: 2013, person

How to get the value of a person or group field value in SharePoint 2013 using jquery.

I have used

```
$("input[title=Field Name]").text()
```

But it is retrieving null. any work around?

Comment: You need to specify where you have this field, and e.g. a screenshot would become helpful. Depending on the case, using SPUtility.js or REST might become easier and more useful, but probably jQuery can be used for it too.

Answer (score 2):

No need for jQuery, you can do it with vanilla Javascript

[image]

All the info you want, need, get is on a hidden Input in a Form:

Since this Field is **before** the visible Input,

```
document.querySelector("input[id^='AssignedTo']")
```

*Get the First Input which id **starts** with AssignedTo*

Get's you that Input:

[image]

See the `value` attribute above

```
eval(document.querySelector("input[id^='AssignedTo']").getAttribute('value'))
```

Gets the value and converts the String to an Array:

[image]

Then it is up to you what you want to do with a JavaScript Array:

The Email is inside the `EntityData` Object:

[image]

Since this is the second item in the Array

the email is:

```
var assignedArr=eval(document.querySelector("input[id^='AssignedTo']").getAttribute('value'));
var dannyEmail = assignedArr[1].EntityData.Email;
```

Comment: +1 for javascript. jQuery fanatics are for the lazy!

Comment: jQuery was great from 2006 till IE9 was released. $.ajax might be the only reason why you would use it today, but the Fetch API (and its polyfill for IE<12) is the future

Comment: I cringe when I see `$.each`, or `.css()`, `.attr()` or `.change()`. Oh well, community is what drives success.

Comment: I switched to WebComponents.... and am about to leave the Microsoft world/community that thinks React (its the new jQuery) has a future

Answer (score 1):

try the below code,

```
// Get People Picker Values
function getEditorPeoplePickerValues(fieldName) { // Field Title
        editorNames = "";
        var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
        var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
        var ppobject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
        editorsInfo = ppobject.GetAllUserInfo();

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < editorsInfo.length; ++i) {
            editorNames += editorsInfo[i].DisplayText + ";#";
        }
    }
```

**calling:**

```
getEditorPeoplePickerValues("Field Title");
```

Also if you have only 1 person column in the form then try this:

```
var sUser = $('div.ms-inputuserfield').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `$('.ms-entity-resolved')[0].textContent`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user details using the following syntax

```
function getUserLoginName(peoplePickerId){
    var loginName = '';
    var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerId + "_TopSpan"];
    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    if(users.length > 0) {
        loginName = users[0].Key;
        //email = users[0].EntityData.Email;
        //title = users[0].EntityData.Title;
    }       
    return loginName;
}
```

If you want to get user id you have to make a rest call. Below is one of the approach I am using

```
function getUserIdByLoginName(loginName) {
    var userId = -1;
    var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='" + loginName + "'";
    $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                userId = data.d.Id;             
            },
            error: function (data) {
                fail(data);
            }
        });
    return userId;
}
```

The script you can write as follows

```
var loginName = getUserLoginName("peopleFieldId"); //e.g: getUserLoginName("supervisor");
var userId = getUserIdByLoginName(loginName);
```

This can be used to update your list item in SharePoint.

Comment: not sure that `getUserIdByLoginName` function is going to return anything other than -1 because it's not using promises.

Comment: I am using 'async: false'. So it will return a value. This snippet has been tested.

Comment: Yep, you are right -- completely missed the async false line. Sorry Venkat. Make sure you are using an older version of jQuery, since the async:false is deprecated. I wouldn't recommend this method, though. See here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157625/why-when-to-use-asyncfalse-in-spservices